# Adding WeakReferences into HashMap via #compute - may I get null or not?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

Let's say I have following implementation of cache, purposed to associate some data (connection pool in my case) with the latest state/version of another object:

```
public class Demo<V> {

    private final Map<Integer, VAR<V>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final ReferenceQueue<V> refq = new ReferenceQueue<>();

    private final Function<Integer, V> factory;

    public Demo(Function<Integer, V> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Demo<Object> demo = new Demo<>(id -> new Object());

        Object data = demo.getCached(1, 0);
        assert data != null;

        WeakReference<Object> keyReference = new WeakReference<>(data);
        data = null;
        while (keyReference.get() != null) {
            System.gc();
            Thread.sleep(1_000);
        }

    }

    public V getCached(int id, int version) {
        assert version >= 0;
        VAR<V> ref = cache.get(id);
        V storedData = ref == null ? null : ref.get();
        int storedVersion = storedData == null ? -1 : ref.getVersion();

        if (storedData == null) {
            cache.remove(id, ref);
        }

        if (storedVersion >= version) {
            return storedData;
        }

        Supplier<VAR<V>> varFactory = () -> {
            V data = factory.apply(id);
            return new WeakVAR(data, id, version);
        };

        BiFunction<Integer, VAR<V>, VAR<V>> replaceFunction = (key, existing) -> {
            V data = existing == null ? null : existing.get();
            if (data == null) {
                return varFactory.get();
            }
            if (existing.getVersion() >= version) {
                return existing;
            }
            return varFactory.get();
        };

        Supplier<V> vFactory = () -> cache.compute(id, replaceFunction).get();

/*
        V result;
        while ((result = vFactory.get()) == null) {
            // nop
        }
        return result;
*/

        return vFactory.get();
    }


    interface VAR<V> {

        int getVersion();

        int getId();

        V get();

    }

    class WeakVAR extends WeakReference<V>
            implements VAR<V> {

        private final int id;

        private final int version;

        public WeakVAR(V referent, int id, int version) {
            super(referent, refq);
            this.id = id;
            this.version = version;
        }

        @Override
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        @Override
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

}
```

The question is: is it possible that `public V getCached(int id, int version)` method may return null when dereferencing `WeakReference` returned from `Map#compute`? If so, what is the best way to overcome this issue? Is busy loop a felicitous solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible that your method returns `null`. In principle, when you have code like this

```java
WeakReference<Object> ref = new WeakReference<>(new Object());
Object o = ref.get();
```

it’s already possible that `o` is `null`.

Instead of creating a loop, you should ensure that there is no phase where the result object is only weakly reachable between the check for an existing object or the creation of a new object and the final return statement.

Or, in other words, enforce that the object is strongly reachable throughout the operation.

For example

```java
public V getCached(int id, int version) {
    // do not abuse assertions for argument checking
    if(version < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    VAR<V> ref = cache.get(id);
    V storedData = ref == null? null: ref.get();

    if(storedData != null && ref.getVersion() >= version) {
        return storedData;
    }

    List<V> strongReference = new ArrayList<>(1);

    cache.compute(id, (key, existing) -> {
        V data = existing == null? null: existing.get();
        if(data != null && existing.getVersion() >= version) {
            strongReference.add(data);
            return existing;
        }
        data = factory.apply(key);
        strongReference.add(data);
        return new WeakVAR(data, key, version);
    });

    return strongReference.get(0);
}
```

The fast path at the beginning does not need additional effort, as the `storedData` variable is already a strong reference, which is consistently used for checking the presence of an old object and returning it.

The function passed to the `compute` method must return the weak reference to conform to the map’s type, hence, it needs an additional storage to keep a strong reference while returning through the `compute` method. The example uses an `ArrayList` but any local object with a reference variable would do.

Often, a single element array is used for such a purpose, but Java doesn’t support creating a `V[]` array. In the end, the overhead doesn’t matter much, as long as the code succeeds in the fast path with the optimistic `get()` often enough.

Comment: thanks, actually I was considering that option as well, however, is it possible the result of `#compute` method may differ from objects seen by remapping function? i.e. may `strongReference` contain not the latest version?

Comment: that "possible", was actually caught as a real defect in the JVM code [a while ago](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8212178)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov in this answer’s code, the result of the `compute` method will always be in sync with the reference stored in `strongReference`. However, your use of `ConcurrentHashMap` suggests that multiple threads are involved. When other threads update the same key after the `compute` completed, there is no guaranty that this method returns the most recent version. But this is not fixable anyway; even if you make the entire `getCached` method `synchronized`, the return value may become outdated the next nanosecond after returning from `getCached`.

Comment: @Holger Hmmm... according to `ConcurrentMap#compute` default implementation it could call remapping function multiple times, so, upon the return of `#compute` method `strongReference` list may contain multiple entries and the first one (0's) will be the most outdated.

Comment: `ConcurrentMap` is the interface which describes the minimum guarantees all implementation must provide. The actual implementation `ConcurrentHashMap` offers stronger guarantees. [It’s `compute` method states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)): “*The entire method invocation is performed atomically. The supplied function is invoked exactly once per invocation of this method.*” My previous comment was made under the assumption that you keep using `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for the link, that really proves even for soft references the busy loop is not a good idea.